# max(row_num) gave me different out than count(*) in oracle.Here is my query

Tags: oracle, count

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT Instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
             Instance.JOB_NAME,
             Instance.JOB_KEY,
             Execution.JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
             Execution.VERSION,
             Execution.CREATE_TIME,
             Execution.START_TIME,
             Execution.END_TIME,
             Execution.STATUS,
             Execution.EXIT_CODE,
             Execution.EXIT_MESSAGE,
             Execution.LAST_UPDATED,
             Execution.JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION
      FROM (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
                   JOB_NAME,
                   JOB_KEY
            FROM PROCESOSBATCH_OWN.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
            order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID) Instance,
           (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
                   VERSION,
                   JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
                   CREATE_TIME,
                   START_TIME,
                   END_TIME,
                   STATUS,
                   EXIT_CODE,
                   EXIT_MESSAGE,
                   LAST_UPDATED,
                   JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION
            FROM PROCESOSBATCH_OWN.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
            WHERE 1 = 1
            order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID) Execution
      where Instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID=Execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
      and Execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID is not null);

  COUNT(*)
----------
      9689
```

```
select max(row_num)
from (SELECT Execution.row_num,
             Instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
             Instance.JOB_NAME,
             Instance.JOB_KEY,
             Execution.JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
             Execution.VERSION,
             Execution.CREATE_TIME,
             Execution.START_TIME,
             Execution.END_TIME,
             Execution.STATUS,
             Execution.EXIT_CODE,
             Execution.EXIT_MESSAGE,
             Execution.LAST_UPDATED,
             Execution.JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION
      FROM (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
                   JOB_NAME,
                   JOB_KEY
            FROM PROCESOSBATCH_OWN.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
            order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID) Instance,
           (SELECT rownum as row_num,
                   JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
                   VERSION,
                   JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
                   CREATE_TIME,
                   START_TIME,
                   END_TIME,
                   STATUS,
                   EXIT_CODE,
                   EXIT_MESSAGE,
                   LAST_UPDATED,
                   JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION
            FROM PROCESOSBATCH_OWN.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
            WHERE 1 = 1
            order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID) Execution
      where Instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID=Execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
      and Execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID is not null);

MAX(ROW_NUM)
------------
        9854
```

Comment: Are you certain that this is actually reproducible, and no other processes are adding/removing records to any tables involved between your two benchmark tests?

Comment: Try with `select count(*), max(rownum) from` in the same query and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Count(*) is returning number of rows from output.
Rownum is Oracle's number of row from SPECIFC table.

You are probably excluding some rows from table PROCESOSBATCH_OWN.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, by the join operation or the where condition.

You can select all rownum with order by and they you will see that some ROWNUMs are mising.

Answer (score 0):

We are not counting maximum of the final result's `rownum`. 
We have defined `row_num` in one of the inner query `rownum as row_num`, on top of which have added some more filters.

Let's say this inner query had returned 10k rows, `max(row_num)` would return 10000 here.
Row numbers from 2000 to 3000 are filtered out in our main query. Since we have defined `rownum as row_num`, `max(row_num)` would still return 10000 meanwhile `max(rownum)` on the very same query would return 9000.

In general, `max(rownum)` would give same result as `count(*)` on same query. Here it is not the case, we are fewtching `max(row_num)` instead of `max(rownum)`, which may differ.

Happy coding!☺